# Humanity's Response to Earth's Destruction?

Tags: science-fiction, psychology

In a science-fiction scenario set several hundred years in the future, most of humanity lives on various O'Neill-type space habitats, with maybe 1/4 to 1/3rd of the total human population living on Earth.  The economies of Earth and the colonies are *mostly* separate when it comes to exchange of physical goods, due to Earth's competitive disadvantage, located at the bottom of its own gravity well.  Earth's primary exports are knowledge-based, since it's more expensive to lift goods out of atmosphere than it is to manufacture in space.

Assume that apart from technological progress and expansion into space, humanity maintains basically the same status quo.  You've got a bunch of nations with a bunch of different outlooks on life, and imperfect but mostly-functional democracy is still the main order of the day.

FTL travel is developed and a war is fought with an aggressive neighboring alien empire, which triggers the same kind of strange bedfellows situation we got in WW2 (America and Britain working with Russia), where human nations that would normally be at each other's throats temporarily put aside their differences.  Let's say that the major human factions have compatible ethics to the major western democracies of the last century.

Now, the war comes to a close, with total human victory... except that Earth was hit with planet-killing weapons, be they antimatter bombs, Little Doctors, or giant rocks.  However the manner of destruction, Earth is rendered uninhabitable and almost all of its population killed.  This is devastating for humanity, but with most of its population and industry in space, it can continue on.

Now, the question is:  How would humanity deal with a species who we have defeated, and is at our mercy, if we're still reeling from having 1 out of every 3 humans killed and our homeworld destroyed by them?

EDIT:  Assume the aliens are psychologically compatible with humans, meaning that they're not inherently wired to kill us.

Comment: Depends too much on the culture of the aliens and the motivation of the war in the first place. E.g. if the aliens are inherently xenophobic - like "neurological wired" to compulsively attack anything non-self - nothing else but utter destruction will do; otherwise, the future will see **at least** a significant number of skirmishes. At the other end of the scale, "cultural mismatch leading to accidental war by uncontrolled escalation", intense diplomacy will do on the long term and only actions to make clear "humanity had won" need to be taken. As such, the Q is plot based and opinions prone.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just look at human history: Something similar to the [Nüremberg trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuremberg_trials) and the [International Military Tribunal for the Far East](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Military_Tribunal_for_the_Far_East) would happen where the humans would execute or imprison the alien top brass and any lower level savages for [genocide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genocide) under Earth Law instead of Alien Law.
2. Another <s>salient</s> historical  fact: Very few people know concentration camps on a large scale were not invented by the Nazis but [by the British during the Boer wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_concentration_camps) so that could be something humanity might fall as low as this if this was a particular gruesome war...
3. [District 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/District_9) comes to mind too and Aliens might be treated as "subhumans"...
4. etc etc

Humans are a particularly nasty species so there are lots of actual historical nastiness you can fall back to.

**Alternatively:**

- Humanity has evolved beyond all of the above, understands the aliens were under a dictatorial regime and now that regime has fallen doesn't hold the actual Alien citizens responsible as they just like their earthly brethren/sistern just want a good life, a better life for their children, and for their government to leave them the hell alone in their pursuits of happiness...

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Without external interference we'll most likely want to exploit them in a forced work situation akin to slavery to recuperate the war costs. They'd likely end up in a situation similar to sweat shops, with poor conditions and treatment and receiving very little for their work, if at all. Additionally, if their planet is close by and has the necessary conditions to sustain life as we know it, we'd likely hijack it as our own.

However I think the primary concern would be rescuing whatever humans and wildlife which managed to survive the planet's destruction. We'd make huge efforts to take in as many specimens as possible in order to attempt to keep the species alive. The remnants of research and preservation efforts, such as the seed ark in the labs in Antartica would likely be top priority. If we did started to occupy their planet as our own and it's life had similar structure, there's a good chance we'd wipe out native animal and plant species to make room for those we managed to rescue. Plus whatever species available in colonies would be gathered together in preservation efforts.

Overall, hate towards the aliens would be obvious, and a good part of humanity would be more than willing to take what they have and adapt it to fit our needs and wishes,essentially colonizing their planet like the Europeans colonized South America, likely with additional measures to ensure their independence was never re-established.